# Why Is My Lazy Loading Page Not Loading Correctly?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lazy-loading

I need help in determining why my page using a [Lazy Loading jQuery library](https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any) isn't working correctly. One element or calendar renders correctly, but the other doesn't. I'm enclosing my div content within the `<div class='lazyload'>` class as specified:

```
...
<div class='main regularslider owac'>
<div class='lazyload'>
<script type='text/lazyload'>
...
</script>
</div>
...
```

Note that the JavaScript wasn't produced by me. 
I'm using this plugin as inspiration (most of the PHP and all of the JavaScript is identical to what I have): https://wordpress.org/plugins/availability-calendar/

Here is my sample web page: https://applicable-owl.jurassic.ninja/apartments/

I expect to see both calendars with clickable buttons on both sides of the calendar, but one calendar always seems to output the entire collection of divs in a linear succession without having any associated JavaScript with it to render the buttons.

Please also note this is a WordPress site and using two shortcodes to render the calendar content, with one shortcode followed by another. 
So I have this with the shortcodes:

```
 [availabilitycalendar apartment="2" language="EN"] 
 [availabilitycalendar apartment="2" language="EN"]
```

I'm attempting to increase the speed of the page because without lazy loading, the page has to wait for all the divs to be created.

A link to the relevant PHP responsible for this: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/availability-calendar/trunk/public/includes/frontend.php#L104

And for the JavaScript (it appears to be using [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) as inspiration) : https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/availability-calendar/trunk/public/js/owac.js

Comment: Looking through that plugin's docs, this looks like an incredibly bad idea. HTML text is _the fastest thing_ that can get loaded; scripts, images, etc. will all take _much longer_ to load than the basic normal HTML, including text. There is no value in lazy loading it, not even if you're loading a 100 page book - in HTML, that's maybe 200kb, uncompressed, and it won't transmit uncompressed, it transmits with gzip/brotli.